# PyQt: Using QTextEdit as editor in a QStyledItemDelegate

Tags: python, pyqt, qtextedit, qitemdelegate, qstyleditemdelegate

I am looking for the **clean way** to use a multi line text edit in the my QStyledItemDelegate. The createEditor implementation is pretty straight forward by returning a QTextEdit instance

```
def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
    return QtGui.QTextEdit("Some text")
```

But `setModelData` expects a Edit Widget derived from `QWidget` as a parameter instead of `QTextEdits` base `QScrollArea`. The Qt Documentation also [tells me](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstyleditemdelegate.html#setModelData) (at least in the PyQt Doc) that the `setModelData` function tries to get the data from the QWidget UserData field. But without having an Edit Widget derived from `QWidget` there is no option in setting the data. Currently it throws a `AttributeError` because it can't find `text()` on the editor.

Is there some proven way to use a non-QWidget editor? Or am I just missing some Widget to do that?

Currently I quick fixed the issue by instanciating a `QLineEdit` with the `QTextEdit` data from `toPlainText()` and passing this to `setModelData`. Very Hacky!! I could also use duck typing and just implement a `text()` method on a `QTextEdit` derivate. But still not a nice way, isn't it? What is a way to do this in C++?

Comment: Yes you are right. I changed it. I also I made a mistake by claiming that `QTextEdit` is not derived from `QWidget` - which in fact it is through `QFrame`

Answer (score 5):

The minimum requirements for an item-delegate are very simple (see the [Model/View Overview](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#a-simple-delegate) for more details). Just create a subclass of [QStyledItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleditemdelegate.html) and reimplement the methods `createEditor`, `setEditorData`, and `setModelData`:

```
class Delegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        return QtGui.QTextEdit(parent)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setText(index.data())

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.toPlainText())
```

With this approach, it's easy to support several different types of editor via the same delegate. For example, an `isinstance` check could be used to decide which type of editor to use. Below is a basic demo that shows how to do this:

[image: screenshot]

```python
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ItemDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        column = index.column()
        if column == 0:
            return QtWidgets.QTextEdit(parent)
        elif column == 1:
            return QtWidgets.QComboBox(parent)
        elif column == 2:
            return QtWidgets.QSpinBox(parent)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
            editor.setText(index.data())
        elif isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QComboBox):
            editor.addItems('Red Blue Green'.split())
            editor.setCurrentIndex(editor.findText(index.data()))
        elif isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QSpinBox):
            editor.setValue(int(index.data()))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
            model.setData(index, editor.toPlainText())
        elif isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QComboBox):
            model.setData(index, editor.currentText())
        elif isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QSpinBox):
            model.setData(index, editor.value())

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(5, 3)
        self.table.setItemDelegate(ItemDelegate(self))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        colours = 'Red Blue Green'.split()
        for row in range(5):
            for column in range(4):
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
                if column == 1:
                    item.setData(QtCore.Qt.EditRole, random.choice(colours))
                elif column == 2:
                    item.setData(QtCore.Qt.EditRole, random.randint(0, 99))
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(600, 100, 375, 225)
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

Comment: That's a quite straight forward approach. Thanks. I hope this doesn't drift into a general discussion, but isn't there a chance that by skipping the base classes super function I miss emitting some signals or some other call?

Comment: @DonHolio. The reimplemented functions do exactly what their names imply, and nothing more. It would be pretty bad design by Qt if that weren't the case. The `QItemDelegate` is specifically designed to be highly customisable (most of its functions are virtual). I have clarified my answer so that the idea of multiple editor types is dealt with separately.

Answer (score 1):

So I took some time and digged deeper into the problem. There are in fact multiple cleaner solutions:

1. Implementing a Property
   I got it to work properly by implementing a QProperty on a subclass of `QTextEdit` which adds the `text` property as USER property to the object. Here is my code:

   ```
   class DelegatableTextEdit(QtGui.QTextEdit):

       @pyqtProperty(str, user=True)
       def text(self):

           return self.toPlainText()

       @text.setter
       def text(self, text):

           self.setText(text)
   ```
2. Using the Factory
   There seems to be an way to solve this by using the Delegates `setDefaultFactory()` method which then takes a `QItemEditorFactory` which has registered a custom editor creator by using the `registerEditor()` function. You can register a custom implementation of the `QItemEditorCreatorBase` class there which has a overriden `createWidget` method (and if needed a `valuePropertyName` function as well). But I haven't tried this one yet

I decided to take the first solution which only needs the custom `QTextEdit` and the overriden `createEditor()` function. Both should work in C++